# GoogleApiClient Location Dialog - Get Yes/No button callback

Tags: android-googleapiclient

[image]

Where would I get callback for the positive/negetive - Yes/No buttons for this dialog?
Also, how can I customize the text on this Dialog?
Instead of *this app* I want to insert my App name. And I don't want the part that says Use Google's location service.......etc.etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.

```
protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        // All required changes were successfully made

                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to

                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```